# Reduce the effect of float number (rounding) error

Tags: floating-point, rounding-error

We are implementing some geometric algorithms but found the effect of float number calculation error is big. Is there any guide lines to reduce this kind of effects?

The algorithms contains many parts and is very complex. One of the example is to calculate the intersects between a line and a spline (serials of bezier curve). When the line position close to the end point of bezier the result is unstable.

Thanks

Comment: Which programming environment/language?

Comment: And which algorithm?  Show us your code.

Comment: We are using Java, but I don't believe this problem is programming language related because every floating point calculation is done by cpu which follows IEEE754 standard.

Answer (score 3):

- Use algorithms which are less sensitive to floating point error (see [numerical stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability))
- Use wider types (ex. `double` instead of `float`)

Comment: Thanks, this is very help. However my problem should be: "how to make the algorithms less sensitive to floating point error?". Is there any general guidelines for this, or any book I need to read about.